# QuickSight - When I am trying to create dataset using Athena in QuickSight

Tags: mysql, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

it is giving the following error,can someone please tell me its solution, thank you :)

error:- An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Access denied when writing to location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check access on your S3 location for Athena.

Simple test first if you are able to create Quicksight view using Table instead of a query.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the error it is clear that the role that you are using with QuickSight doesn't have proper permissions defined for S3.

Please update it with proper S3 permissions for the bucket that you are trying to write to.